# How to get the index of an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
protected double[] cpi = { 10, 10.1, 10.3, 11.6, 13.7, 16.5 }
  protected CharSequence[] fromDate = { 
          "1914",
          "1915",
          "1916",
          "1917",
          "1918",
          "1919"};
  protected CharSequence[] toDate = { 
          "1914",
          "1915",
          "1916",
          "1917",
          "1918",
          "1919"};
```

I am trying the following:

```
double factor = cpi[frmDate[k]] / cpi [toDate[k]];
```

I get the following error for both:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to int
>
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to int

What I am trying to do is... If the selection for `fromDate` is index = 2 and `toDate` is index = 3 then calculate the following:

```
double factor = cpi[10.3] / cpi[11.6];
```

Comment: What do you think `cpi[10.3]` means?

Comment: `cpi[10.3]` is taking the index of selected `fromDate` and getting the value from `cpi`

Comment: you need to use the index position of the element, not the actual element value, so more like `cpi[2]/cpi[3]`

Comment: `cpi[10.3]` is an example to show what should be there but I see what you mean :)

Comment: What @SotiriosDelimanolis is trying to say: the part between the `[]` is the index for the lookup. How is `10.3` an index? Differently said: if you're asked to drink the beer in glass number `10.3` - what would you do?

Comment: As @kabuto178 said, it should be `cpi[2]/cpi[3]` but I showed the value in the example in my question rather than the index to help understand.

Comment: @MH Pick up the glass closest to me and drink it.  Then tell them I don't understand the question.  Seems obvious ... :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want this :

```
protected double[] cpi = { 10, 10.1, 10.3, 11.6, 13.7, 16.5 }
  protected CharSequence[] fromDate = { 
          "1914",
          "1915",
          "1916",
          "1917",
          "1918",
          "1919"};
  protected CharSequence[] toDate = { 
          "1914",
          "1915",
          "1916",
          "1917",
          "1918",
          "1919"};
String year1 = "1915";
String year2 = "1918";
indexYear1 = Arrays.asList(fromDate).indexOf(year1); //find the position (index) of year1 => 1
indexYear2 = Arrays.asList(toDate).indexOf(year2); //find the position (index) of year2 => 4
double factor = cpi[indexYear1] / cpi[indexYear2]; // => 10.1 / 13.7
```

Comment: `fromDate` and `toDate` are selection index that can change based on user and is never constant.

Comment: Maybe this might work. If x is representing the charsequence array. Than I can take the value that from the selection and match it up and get the index? Does `x` represent the charsequence variable?

Comment: That will work because I can get the text value of each instead of hardcoded year and get the index. Let me test it out. I have it working but it's not effecient.

Comment: It is O(n) so it is efficient. It can be O(log n) with some Map classes, but you spent more time in adding/removing O(n*log n)

Comment: I meant the way I did my coding :)... your seems fine just haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: Well your code was not functional in first place :D, if it works, it would be efficient :).

Comment: :D it's fixed now. I did it differently. My app array had more but was was messing up the calculation was... I had some missing values in one of the array so it wasn't adding up! I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
double factor = cpi[k] / cpi[j];
```

Where `k` is the selection index for `frmDate` and where `j` is the selection index for `toDate`.

Because right now, you're trying to use the Strings as an index for the array. I assume you want to use the same index for the `cpi` array.

In order to compute `k` and `j`, create a function `getIndex(CharSequence[] array, CharSequence item)`.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
private int getIndex(CharSequence[] array, CharSequence item) {
    for(int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        if array[a] is item
            return a;
    }
    return -1; //not in it
}
```

Comment: The OP actually asks how to compute `k` and `j`.

Comment: I am actually using the K for both so J doesn't come in to play.

Comment: Assuming you are using `frmDate[k]`, I assume the OP already knows what `k` is. Although if they don't correspond directly, I will add in another section.

Comment: I am using K for both array but assigning it differently based on the selection. I think that's where the issue is.